# PostgresSQL. Difference in casting a timestamp as a date compared to explicitly defining the whole timestamp in a WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, date, casting, where-clause

I have a SQL query with two WHERE clause versions:

First (Explicit timestamps):

```
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2017-07-06 00:00:00.0' AND '2017-07-20 00:00:00.0' AND doc->>'sensorId' != '7777777'
```

Resulting row count = 15477

Second (Cast as Dates):

```
WHERE created_at::date BETWEEN '2017-07-06'::date AND '2017-07-20'::date AND doc->>'sensorId' != '7777777'
```

Resulting row count = 18679

The created_at column contains timestamps with no timezone in the form of '2017-07-06 08:41:34.574686'

The length of the milliseconds differs between 5 and 6 digits.

I realize this is likely created by casting the timestamp as a date, but I have no understanding of why this happens, if someone could please explain.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot... the first query should be AND '2017-07-21 00:00:00.0'

Answer (score 0):

When you use timepstamp you have

```
BETWEEN '2017-07-06 00:00:00.0' AND '2017-07-20 00:00:00.0'
```

It means that every event after '2017-07-20 00:00:00.0' (for example '2017-07-20 12:15:11') is out of scope.

You should use '2017-07-21 00:00:00.0' for timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already given, but I'll try to give a bit more detailed explaination.

Assume you have a row with `2017-07-20 12:34:56` in `created_at` column.

In your second query, you truncate time (hours, minutes, etc) from column values:

```
WHERE created_at::date ...
```

So `2017-07-20 12:34:56` converts to `2017-07-20` and `BETWEEN` conditions meet (`'2017-07-20' <= '2017-07-20'::date` is TRUE), and this row will be taken.

While in the first query, you take `created_at` as is, and then compare it with `'2017-07-20 00:00:00.0'` in `BETWEEN` – so that the first query will not take our row (because `'2017-07-20 12:34:56' <= '2017-07-20 00:00:00.0'` is FALSE).

That's why the second query returns more rows than the first one.

Comment: Thank you :) I was thinking originally that there was some strange conversions happening with the casting maybe, then I realised the above, think I've been staring at SQL for too long.